# How do I run Asterisk as user other than root?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, centos, asterisk

I compiled Asterisk 11 from source as user root on CentOS. Now I want Asterisk to run as user asterisk group asterisk. I have uncommented

`AST_USER="asterisk"`

`AST_GROUP="asterisk"`

in

`/etc/sysconfig/asterisk`

I have also tried uncommenting the same variables in

`/usr/local/src/asterisk-11.17.1/contrib/init.d/etc_default_asterisk`

I restart service asterisk and even reboot the server with the referred condition and when I

`ps ax | grep asterisk` ,

I still get

`4457 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk`

`4459 pts/0    Sl     0:01 /usr/sbin/asterisk -f -vvvg -c`

instead of

`4457 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk -U asterisk -G asterisk`

`4459 pts/0    Sl     0:01 /usr/sbin/asterisk -f  -U asterisk -G asterisk -vvvg -c`

Please, note that UNIX user asterisk and UNIX group asterisk do exist in my system.

I kindly ask you to tell me how to proceed to get asterisk running as asterisk in group asterisk. By the way, if you add directions on which files and directories to change permissions on, to get asterisk running as I need, would be great.

Feedback will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your output not mean that asterisk use root user

Use

```
ps al|grep asterisk
```

Second column is uid of process.